# How can I package a symlink with cpack?

Tags: cmake, symlink, packaging, deb, cpack

I've seen many linux applications packaged with their binaries in some path like `/opt/mypkg/myexecutable` and a symlink to it in `/usr/bin`. I've seen these symlinks in the packaged files.

I want to do the same while packaging my software with cpack, creating deb and rpm packages with CPackDEB and CPackRPM.

- Is it possible to create a symlink to an arbitrary, possibly non existent path?
- Could I then use `INSTALL(FILES "mysymlink" DESTINATION /usr/bin/myapp COMPONENT MyComponent)`? (Would there be problems with symlinks being followed when the destination actually exists?)
- Could I change the link destination with something like `CONFIGURE_FILE()`

Or am I just missing a cpack directive that does the job correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the following example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(myls NONE)

execute_process(COMMAND ln -s /opt/myapp/superls myls)

install(FILES ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/myls DESTINATION /usr/bin/myapp COMPONENT MyComponent)

SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_CONTACT dmarquant)
include(CPack)
```

You can simply create a symlink to a non existing location and as you have written install it with install(FILES ...).

Comment: This works well for installation, but while packaging, this causes to add the folder/target too for which I want to add the symlink. Any alternative you can suggest?